# Apollo query fails with an error - TypeError: this.props.getPostInfo is not a function

Tags: reactjs, apollo, react-apollo, graphql-js

I am trying to use `Apollo` with `React` to connect to my `graphql` api endpoint. In order to do this , I have a component as follows.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {GetPostInfoQuery} from "./../../../queries/posts"
import { compose, graphql, Query } from "react-apollo";


class PostItem extends Component {

  getCurrentPostInfo =() => {
    this.props.getPostInfo({
            variables: {
                postID: "UG9zdDoy"
            }
        })
        .then((loading, data, error) => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error) );
        });

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button  onClick={this.getCurrentPostInfo}> Load Info </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default compose(
    graphql(GetPostInfoQuery, {
        name: "getPostInfo"
    })
)(PostItem);
```

My `GetPostInfoQuery` looks like as follows

```
export const GetPostInfoQuery = gql `
query postInfo($postID: ID!){
   post(id:$postID) {
     id
     title
     content
     headerImage
     createdAt
     user {
       id 
       firstname
       lastname
       locale {
         id
         name
         country
       }
     }
     tagList {
       edges{
         node {
           id
           name
         }
       }
     }
   }
}
`
```

I am passing a variable - `postID` whose value is `UG9zdDoy` to my query so that it can get executed and return me the data back. When I run the exact query using the `graphiql` interface it returns me data without any issue .

When I run the above code, I am getting the following error 
[image]

and here is the same query running in `graphiql`

[image]

Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `graphql` HOC behaves differently depending on whether it receives a `query` or  `mutation`. From [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#graphqlquery-configcomponent):

> [For queries,] the higher-order component created when using graphql() will feed a data prop into your component... The data prop contains the data fetched from your query in addition to some other useful information and functions to control the lifecycle of your GraphQL-connected component.
>
> The higher order component created when you pass a mutation to graphql() will provide your component with a single prop named mutate. Unlike the data prop which you get when you pass a query to graphql(), mutate is a function.

In other words, for queries you get a `data` prop that's an object and for mutations you get `mutate` prop that's a function. You're using a query, so you can't call the prop you receive like a function because it's not a function, like the error indicates.

If you want to trigger a query in response to some user action, you can call the `query` method on the client directly. See [withApollo](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo/#withapollocomponent) for more details.